# Как поменять дату местами, если у меня тип String? java

Tags: java, дата, android-layout

Моя проблема заключается в том, что я получаю данные из `Retrofit` и сохраняю все данные из файла в массив. И когда я обращаюсь к массиву, чтобы перевернуть дату, у меня появляется ошибка в `setText`, потому что он не принимает `LocalData`

Получение данных:

```
    public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
        Example examples = response.body();
         for(int i = 0; i < examples.getResponse().size(); i++){
            String f_name = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getfName();
            String l_name = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getlName();
            String SpecName = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getSpecialty()
                                             .iterator().next().getName();
            String SpecId =  response.body().getResponse().iterator().next().getSpecialty()
                                             .iterator().next().getSpecialtyId().toString();
            String AvatarUrl = response.body().getResponse().get(i).getAvatrUrl();

            DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(response.body().getResponse().get(i).getBirthday(), format);

            workerList.add(new Worker(f_name, l_name, date, SpecName, SpecId, AvatarUrl));

         }
        setPersonRecycler(workerList);
    }
```

Теперь сам Holder:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PersonViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.lname.setText(workerList.get(position).getLname());
        holder.fname.setText(workerList.get(position).getFname());
        holder.birthday.setText(workerList.get(position).getBirthday());
        Picasso.with(context).load(workerList.get(position).getAvatarUrl()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.SpecName.setText(workerList.get(position).getSpecName());
        holder.id.setText(workerList.get(position).getSpecId());
    }
```

Ошибка такова:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.time.LocalDate)'
```

Comment: Нужно не "переворачивать" дату, а отформатировать с помощью нужного форматтера, чтобы получился String, потом уже передавать в setText

Comment: @insolor, подскажешь как именно это сделать? Просто, я пока новенький в данной тематике

Comment: Вам не надо что либо менять местами. TextView отображает только строки (тип String), соответственно дату нужно преобразовать в этот тип. У класса LocalDate есть метод toString() , который, как можно понять из названия, преобразует дату в строку, но таким способом дату нельзя отформатировать по своему шаблону, есть только один дефолтный вариант, если он вам не подходит, то для других форматов вывода используется метод format(), который тоже вернет строку, но согласно установленного шаблона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего переворачивать не нужно, нужно всего лишь отформатировать. К примеру так:

```
LocalDate birthday = workerList.get(position).getBirthday();
holder.birthday.setText(birthday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

Comment: `LocalDate` вставать нужно в `onBindViewHolder?` Или же при внесении данных в массив?
Просто если это делать в моменте получения данных, то Retrofit всегда ожидает `String`, если же в `Holder`, то все ровно ожидается с `String`